# Uploaded NodeJS Discord Bot to Online Host Using Pteradactyl Daemon having MODULE_NOT_FOUND errors

Tags: node.js, discord.js, hosting

I started using an online host recently called Oxide for their cheap Discord Bot Hosting services, but when I upload my files to the server and try and run it I get MODULE_NOT_FOUND errors:

```
Error: Cannot find module '../database/models/blacklistSchema'
Require stack:
- /home/container/commands/blacklist.js
- /home/container/bot.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:815:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:667:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:887:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/container/commands/blacklist.js:1:19)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:999:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:863:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:708:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:887:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/container/bot.js:19:21)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:999:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:863:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:708:14) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [ '/home/container/commands/blacklist.js', '/home/container/bot.js' ]
```

I use MongoDB and have a subdirectory for databases, and haven't had any issues running it locally on my own computer. I've tried Googling answers and tried looking to some documentation to provide further instruction but I'm just not all that familiar with Linux and I'm still rather fairly new to NodeJS itself, but not JavaScript.

In the command, the first line is:
`const Blacklist = require('../database/models/blackListSchema');`

And in the same directory as bot.js I have /database/models and all the necessary files required.

Answer (score 0):

Probably You are using the packages installed in node_modules for your operative system and not for the OS of the hosting.

Try to remove `node_modules` directory and the `package-lock.json` file, then run

```
npm install
```

to install angain all the packages for the current OS.